I just installed pacman on kubuntu 24.04. How can I add a package repository
Perhaps I could use the apt package repository?
If so, how do I specify the location of that repository?
Does it make sense to use pacman on a kubuntu setup?

Welcome to SuperUser. What research have you done regarding adding repositories to Kubuntu? Also, please note that we only allow a single question per post, and questions like "does it make sense to..." are asking for opinion and conjecture, and such questions are also off topic here. Please read the Help section to better understand how this site works and what is and is not on topic here.


Perhaps I could use the apt package repository?

No. They use different package formats, so pacman will not know what to do with a .deb file.
In general, no, it does not make sense to use pacman on Ubuntu, except for installing a fresh system (it is packaged for the sole purpose of making an Arch Linux container on Ubuntu, similar to how one could 'debootstrap' Ubuntu on an Arch system). If you try to use it to install packages on the same system that is already managed by apt/dpkg, however, you'll likely end up with a broken system:

the two package managers won't know what is already installed through the other one, so you'll end up with two copies of everything;
most Linux distributions that use pacman don't use quite the same file paths as Debian/Ubuntu (e.g. /libexec vs /lib/foo);
where the paths are the same, installation of the same thing through the other package manager will fail due to pacman refusing to trash files that already exist;
and so on.

It has been done in the past (for example), but requires a bit of care. (Possibly to the point of hand-editing the package databases, really.)
